# Form error management in symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

Im trying to guess why the form I submit is not valid, since my Entity has no constraints.

I pass to the twig template `'error' => $form->getErrors()` but then I have no idea how to show in the twig the error message

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html):

```
{{ form_errors(form.fooProperrty) }}
```

And

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

If I may guess, your form is not validating because you forgot to render the csrf token, which you can render by doing

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot